# IE does not support the spread operator (...) how to fix this issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
    var cars = [{
    make: "audi",
    model: "r8",
    year: "2012"
    },
    {
    make: "audi",
    model: "rs5",
    year: "2013"
    },
    {
    make: "ford",
    model: "mustang",
    year: "2012"
    },
    {
    make: "ford",
    model: "fusion",
    year: "2015"
    },
    {
    make: "kia",
    model: "optima",
    year: "2012"
    }];    
var group = cars.reduce((r, a) => {
        console.log("a", a);
        console.log('r', r);
r[a.make] = [...r[a.make] || [], a];
return r;
}, {});
```

I want to make it a group of an array but This code doesn't work in IE so can anyone help me out to make it work in IE browser.

Comment: JQuery's benefits really come into play when querying and manipulating the DOM. Your code is mostly array work, which JQuery isn't going to be able to make any simpler. The native JavaScript Array API is already quite robust and concise.

Comment: what is that you have tried to change the code to Jquery... please show the code you tried so far

Comment: "I need this code in jquery."  Why?  To need something is to have a problem.  What's the problem?  My assuption is it is a readability issue, which isn't jQuery related.

Comment: Can you explain the reason, why you need it in JQuery?
As JQuery is designed to simplify HTML DOM tree traversal and manipulation, as well as event handling, and apart from that everything you can manage from javascript.

Comment: This code doesnot works in IE browsers so i need to make it work in IE browser as well. Thats the only reason

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: It doesn't work in IE because IE does not support the spread operator (...).

Comment: @Taplar what can i do to make that work in IE browser

Comment: First off, update your question to reflect your actual issue to increase your chance of getting more eyes on it.  And secondly, double check your snippet you provided.  I copied and pasted it into a snippet runner and it has a syntax error.

Comment: @Taplar i have added full code that you can test

Comment: You still have a syntax error with a `[` not being closed around the `r[a.make` line.

Comment: @Taplar corrected the syntax error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The modified answer address two issues with IE.

1. IE does not support arrow functions
2. IE does not support the spread operator

So the logic is pretty simple.  If the make key is not in the result, put a new empty array in the result for the key.  And then just push the value to it.

```js
var cars = [{
    make: "audi",
    model: "r8",
    year: "2012"
  },
  {
    make: "audi",
    model: "rs5",
    year: "2013"
  },
  {
    make: "ford",
    model: "mustang",
    year: "2012"
  },
  {
    make: "ford",
    model: "fusion",
    year: "2015"
  },
  {
    make: "kia",
    model: "optima",
    year: "2012"
  }
];
var group = cars.reduce(function(r, a) {
  r[a.make] = (r[a.make] || []);
  r[a.make].push(a);
  return r;
}, {});

console.log(group);
```

Comment: @SriVenkataPavanKumarMHS feel free to prove that as an another answer to provide readers options.